# format input to ts object in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am having some data with a time column expressed in week.year and a corresponding unit that was measured in that week.

```
    Week-Year             Units
    01.2020             39.12727273
    02.2020             33.34545455
    03.2020             118.7181818
    04.2020             83.71818182
    05.2020             58.56985
    .                    .
    52.2020             89.54651534
```

I have to create a **ts** object which takes these Week-Year values as input. 
The reason for requiring this step is- there are sometimes values missing for certain weeks so using an auto generated time scale (start=, end=, frequency=) will mess up the readings. 
Is there any way of achieving it? or is there any way to accommodate such a situation?
R novice here, would really appreciate some guidance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input is the data frame `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, convert it to a zoo object and then use `as.ts` to create a `ts` series with frequency 52.

```
library(zoo)

week <- as.integer(DF[[1]])
year <- as.numeric(sub("...", "", DF[[1]]))
z <- zoo(DF[[2]], year + (week - 1) / 52)
tt <- as.ts(z)

tt
## Time Series:
## Start = c(2020, 1) 
## End = c(2020, 52) 
## Frequency = 52 
##  [1]  39.12727  33.34545 118.71818  83.71818  58.56985        NA        NA
##  [8]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
## [15]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
## [22]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
## [29]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
## [36]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
## [43]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
## [50]        NA        NA  89.54652

frequency(tt)
## [1] 52

class(tt)
## [1] "ts"
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "    Week-Year             Units
    01.2020             39.12727273
    02.2020             33.34545455
    03.2020             118.7181818
    04.2020             83.71818182
    05.2020             58.56985
    52.2020             89.54651534"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, colClasses = c("character", NA))
```

Comment: the input is in fact a data frame. And thanks :) it works :)

Comment: facing a subsequent error since my dataset has changed.I am now dealing with a list of dataframes & need to create a list of ts objs such that each ts obj corresponds to a dataframe(i.e. first ts obj for first data frame & so on.) I tried tweaking the solution provided above: tt <-list()
for (i in num_of_unique_keys)
{
  week <-ds2[[i]][[1]]
  year <- as.numeric(sub("...", "", ds2[[i]][[1]]))
  z <- zoo(ds2[[i]][[2]], year + (week - 1) / 52)
  tt[i] <- as.ts(z)
} i am getting error- Error in seq.default(head(tt, 1), tail(tt, 1), deltat) : 
'from' must be a finite number

Comment: Need a reproducible example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549725/creating-list-of-ts-objects-based-on-list-of-dataframes-in-r the updated query.

Comment: Hey I figured out what my problem is- For those dataframes where CAL.YEAR do not start with the first week i.e. 1.xxxx It gives periodicity error. I think what needs to be tweaked is this- "year + (week - 1) / 52)". Can you please explain the logic behind this.

Comment: I don't think so. If I remove the first row of DF in the Note at the end it still works correctly.

Comment: It works well if the WEEK.YEAR starts with the first week i.e. 01.2020 but if it starts wit something like 15.2019 or 26.2020 it is giving me the periodicity error

Comment: I can't reproduce that. If I run `DF <- structure(list(Week.Year = c("15.2020", "16.2020", "17.2020", 
"18.2020", "19.2020", "20.2020"), Units = c(39.12727273, 33.34545455, 
118.7181818, 83.71818182, 58.56985, 89.54651534)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))` and then run the code in the answer there are no errors.

Comment: is there a way to share my dataset?

Comment: Try to cut it down while keeping the problem.